# Kiosk Mode on non-managed Chromeboxes?

Tags: google-chrome-app, kiosk, kiosk-mode, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to turn on Kiosk mode for an non-managed chrome box following the [official instructions](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en) but when I'm on the `chrome://extensions` page in developer mode there is no **Add kiosk application** option.

Did this get removed at some point leaving kiosk mode only available to managed devices?

**Edit**
The kiosk mode app I was using was a simple one that I wrote and had loaded via the "unpacked extension" box on the extensions page.

Then I published it restricted to test accounts and included the account on the chromebox as a tester and loaded it from the chrome web store that way.  The effect is the same and I still don't see the kiosk application options.

**Double Edit**
I published it unlisted and installed it.  The app installs and works. I have `"kiosk_enabled" : true` in my manifest and I still don't see any kiosk mode option.

Comment: For the record, do you have the Kiosk-enabled app already installed?

Comment: Do you see a Manage Kiosk Applications... button along the top of the page?

Comment: I have it loaded as an unpacked extension downloaded to the chrome box.  I can open it and it runs full screen.  There is no Manage Kiosk Applications button.

Comment: When you check the Developer Mode box on chrome://extensions, a Manage Kiosk Applications button should appear. If it doesn't this might be a Chrome bug. Bugs [272079](http://crbug.com/272079) and [385943](http://crbug.com/385943) both sound similar to what you are describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the manage kiosk button to show up by:

- Removing other users.  The first user on the machine is designated the owner.  I was trying for kiosk mode from the second user.
- Restarting the device

After the reboot the Manage Kiosk Applications button was enabled.  The solution is hinted at in this bug from 2014: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=385943